# getDefaultSharedPreferences loop problems with calculating Highscores

Tags: java, android, loops, opengl-es, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to use SharedPreferences to store my highscores in. Every time my level ends, it will call this class with sending the highscore and context with it.

To calculate the position of the score, I make it check the score against the scores which are in the shared prefs (total 6)

My problem, when I have a highscore, (nr 1.) it will automatically copy the same score to second, third, fourth etc. It's not logic to my what is happening. Should it not first set the values of the variables, and then in my loop using those variables?
The below statement is only if the highscore is nr 1. The other statements are actually acting the same.

Score class, will be called from my game class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;



public class Scores  {


private SharedPreferences mSharedPrefs;


public  void input(int i,Context a){

 int first=0;
  int second=0;
  int third=0;
  int fourth=0;
  int fifth=0;
  int sixth=0;



mSharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(a);

sixth=mSharedPrefs.getInt("scoresixth",0);
fifth=mSharedPrefs.getInt("scorefifth",0);  
fourth= mSharedPrefs.getInt("scorefourth",0);
third=mSharedPrefs.getInt("scorethird",0);
second=mSharedPrefs.getInt("scoresecond",0);
first = mSharedPrefs.getInt("scorefirst",0);



if (i>=first){
     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPrefs.edit();


     editor.putInt("scoresixth",fifth);

     editor.putInt("scorefifth",fourth);

     editor.putInt("scorefourth",5);

     editor.putInt("scorethird",second);

     editor.putInt("scoresecond",first);

     editor.putInt("scorefirst",i);

      editor.commit();



}

}
```

Now a piece of my game class where I call the score:

```
public class LevelOne extends GLGame {

    public Screen getStartScreen() {



    return new GameScreen(this);
    }
     class GameScreen extends Screen {
  Scores scorein=new Scores();     ...

 ...     if(score>1499){
          Assets.font.drawText(batchertwo, "    WINNER!!", -200,((1-9/0.4f)/1.5f)*dim);
            win=true;
           scorein.input(score, getApplicationContext());
```

edit: I call the class from an OpenGL screen. Not sure if this will effect any

Problem above solved:
 I call this score class out of an OpenGL screen. The thing with an OpenGL screen is that it keeps on updating the screen, and therefore keeps on calling the  score Input method with all these updates.
That's why I saw my highscore in all positions.

I simply create a Boolean in my OpenGL, where I set it to false/true when it has executed one time. No need to worry about the other updates. It works like never before.

Comment: Have you checked the input into the function? (Print out i)

Comment: Yes, I call the sharedprefs in my highscore screen. When I hard code the score, let's say, 99 it works perfectly. That's why I think something is not right with the variables.

Comment: where do you hardcode the 99?

Comment: "if" I hard code I hard code it as: editor.putInt("scoresecond",99);

Comment: If there are other loops, the problem might lie there

Comment: all highscores show 99 now. When I do ("scorefourth",5) I get the first three as 99, and the last three as 5. It looks like it reads the code upside down.

Comment: @Riverside- can you go ahead and post the whole function?

Comment: I updated the whole example, but I commented out my old code. So the above won't work. The snippet where I call the score might be of any value. I didn't had other loops before because of testing.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong unless there is a bug in how you're storing in shared preferences in places where you have a high score that is not the very highest

Comment: that's why it's frustrates me all day long already. Tried all kind of stuff already but it seems the variable is always referring back to the original